# GraphicsMagick adds black surroundings to transparent image

Tags: node.js, image, imagemagick, png, graphicsmagick

I'm using GraphicsMagick for node.js and I'm trying to edit the attached image but unfortunately it adds a black contour and I don't know why. Maybe it it because I transform it from png to jpeg? Any help is much appreciated!
   [image]
[image]

```
gm(image.file.path)
    .quality(70)
    .strip()
    .samplingFactor(4, 2)
    .interlace('JPEG')
    .colorspace('sRGB');
```

Comment: @MarkSetchell sort of. I noticed the black surroundings are added after I convert the image from PNG to JPEG so I changed the background color using `magick convert image.png --background white -alpha remove -alpha off image.jpg` and the black parts dissapeared

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak `node` but try something like this to set the background colour to yellow and then flatten the image with transparency over the top.

```
gm(image.file.path)
.quality(70)
.strip()
.background('yellow'),
.flatten()
.samplingFactor(4, 2)
.interlace('JPEG')
.colorspace('sRGB');
```

[image]